# Custom Soft keyboard Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-input-method, soft-keyboard

Im creating a softkeyboard Input Method service and I was wondering if it is possible to add several layout layers for instance placing the keyboard within a FrameLayout and then showing it within that Frame layout when you click on an Edit Text field?

My thought process for this is that Im trying to create a keyboard for extremely small screens such as Smart Watch Devices and Im trying to tackle the issue of having small buttons and big fingers. Ive actually developed what i want to do within an actual conventional app but Im having trouble getting the layout to show properly as in Input Method Service